# Calculus find $dx/dt$ using the given information

Tags: calculus

Assume that $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$. Find $dx/dt$ using the following information.

$$x^2+y^2=2.92$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-2$$ when $x=-0.6$ and $y=1.6$.

Comment: What happens when you differentiate implicitly $$ \ \frac{d}{dt} \ [ x^2 + y^2 ] \ = \ \frac{d}{dt} [ 2.92 ] \ \ ? $$

Answer (score 2):

Apply the derivative $\frac{d}{d t}$ to both sides of the equation:

$$\frac{d}{d t} ( x^2 + y^2 ) = \frac{d}{dt} ( 2.92 ).$$

Use the chain rule on the left-hand side, and simplify the right-hand side:

$$ 2 x \frac{d x}{d t} + 2 y \frac{d y}{d t} = 0.$$

Plug in all of the information ($\frac{d y}{d t} = -2$, $x = -0.6$, $y = 1.6$), and solve for $\frac{d x}{d t}$.